# How can I mark a field which represent the time that events occurred?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using kibana to search the document of elasticsearch, I found that  kibana marked some filed ,which represents the time that event occurred.
[image]
When I search index with such documents ,I can make use of the datetime picker
[image]
I noticed that if some documents(in other index) without such field , the datetime picker is missing . So how can I  select  a field and marked as event time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is in the index patterning level:

When creating your index pattern you should be able to choose the "Time filter field name".
There you can choose the `date` field and then the datetime picker will be available.

If you don't seem to have it in your current index pattern - create a new one and use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you declare your index mapping, apply the [`null_value` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date-params). It could simply have the value 0 (0th epoch second). That way, when you select the max date range, it's going to pull all your docs.